# What are the lyrics to Ben Gold and Audrey Gallagher's song "There Will Be Angels"

Tags: lyrics, electronic-music

[Ben Gold and Audrey Gallagher - There Will Be Angels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kqv-X3CiJy4)

Web searches for the song reveal nothing.

Comment: he has a [twitter feed](https://twitter.com/BenGoldMusic?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor) - could you request lyrics via that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user added the lyrics in the comment section of the video:

> To my lover I give
>   all I have to offer
>   Him when he comes
>
> Too shamelessly, totally
>   too easily led
>   Too tempted to be so pure
>
> There'll be angels
>   There'll be glorious redemption
>   When he comes
>
> Too shamelessly, totally
>   too easily led
>   Too tempted to be so pure
>   There'll be angels
>   There'll be angels (x2)﻿